# Render N times component based on the data in object

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new at React. Will be glad if someone can help:
I have parent (Dashboard) which contains all data. This data is passed to the children component (OnBoardingCard). 
How can I render n times the OnBoardingCard component based on the data in the object at Dashboard without using the [num](in this case 3 times - 3x OnBoarding Cards;)?

Thank you!!

Parent- Dashboard

```
const cardData = [
{
    svg: icon1,
    title: 'Add',
    content: 'add more'}, 
{
    svg: icon2,
    title: 'remove',
    content: 'remove'

},
{
    svg: icon3,
    title: 'move',
    content: 'move down'

}];

class Dashboard extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <Section>
           <OnboardingCard listData={cardData}/>
        </Section>

    );
} }
```

Children- OnBoardingCard

```
import Dashboard from "../../../../screens/Dashboard/index.js"; 
class OnboardingCard extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className={styles.cardHolder}>
    <div className={styles.fullCard}>
      <div className={styles.onboardingCard}>
        <div className={styles.iconBackground}>
          <img src={this.props.listData[0].svg} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.title}>{this.props.listData[0].title}</div>
      </div>
      <p className={styles.cardDescription}>
        {this.props.listData[0].content}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
); }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Section>
 <div className={styles.cardRow}>
   {cardData.map((card, i) => (
     <OnboardingCard {...card} key={i} />
   ))}
 </div>        
</Section>
```

This is what I meant (and wanted to do). So this solves my question. Thanks everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use map function,

like this,

```
{this.props.listData.map((item)=>
  <div className={styles.cardHolder}>
    <div className={styles.fullCard}>
      <div className={styles.onboardingCard}>
        <div className={styles.iconBackground}>
          <img src={item.svg} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.title}>{item.title}</div>
      </div>
      <p className={styles.cardDescription}>
        {item.content}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>)}
```

Comment: Thank you, but cardData prop is at the Dashboard (parent) not the child one. :/

Comment: that was just for your reference, use props there. i.e. `this.props.listData`

Answer (score 2):

When you are using a map inside render assign a unique key to its child component.

```
render(){
 return(
    {this.props.listData.map((item, i) => 
     <div className={styles.cardHolder} key={i}>
      <div className={styles.fullCard}>
       <div className={styles.onboardingCard}>
        <div className={styles.iconBackground}>
         <img src={this.props.listData[0].svg} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.title}>{this.props.listData[0].title}</div>
      </div>
      <p className={styles.cardDescription}>
       {this.props.listData[0].content}
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
   )}
 );
}
```